# rails 4 - no routes matches error with curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, curl

I'm trying to implement an API with rails 4.

When access the API through the browser

```
http://api.myapp.dev/v1/users/1.json
```

The JSON response is correct. But when I try to get the JSON using curl

```
curl http://api.myapp.dev/v1/users/1.json
```

It returns a html, but basically the error is *no route matches [GET] "users/1"*

this is my routes file.

```ruby
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  #routes for API
  constraints subdomain: 'api' do
    scope module: 'api' do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :users, :only => [:show]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My controller is

```ruby
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

when I run `rake routes`, the route exists:

```
v1_user GET    /v1/users/:id(.:format)    api/v1/users#show {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

Is necessary an extra configuration?

**UPDATE**
I'm using [prax](https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax) as proxy server

Comment: Open up your inspector in chrome and go to the network tab before making the request from the browser, and go to the network tab. Right click the request and choose "copy as curl request" and try that

Comment: I try it with no results. Curl is returning nothing.

Comment: Now is working. I clean the browser cache and restart prax.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to tell that you accept `json` responses:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://api.myapp.dev/v1/users/1.json
```

Comment: Thanks, but curl returns `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. I'm using prax.

Comment: Now is working. I clean the browser cache and it works, even without the header.